# Simple java game ,problems with creating a timer

Tags: java, eclipse, timer

I am creating a simple game where you control a ball and you avoid other moving obstacles for as long as possible,

The idea is that there will be a timer, that will start at 0 and after around 10 seconds, it is going to add move on to another level, with more moving obstacles.

I have some problems creating a timer, that will start the count, I tried using doing this:

```
        public static void timer(){

        int count = 0;
        while (count<10) {
        try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        count++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);}}
```

The timer starts, but for some reason, the program doesnt like the "Thread Sleep" part, and all the graphics dissepear from the JFrame. The game is still running behind. Is there perhaps any better way to do what I am trying to do?

UPDATE: Below is my class for the game, without my timer attmept:p

```
public class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

Timer mainT;
User user;

int Obstaclesnum = 5;
int levelnumber  = 1;


static ArrayList<Obstacles> obstacles = new ArrayList<Obstacles>();
Random rand  = new Random();

public Game() {

    setFocusable(true);

    user = new User(270,250);
    addKeyListener(new Key(user));

    mainT = new Timer (10,this);
    mainT.start();

    startgame();


    for (int i=0;i<Obstaclesnum;i++){
    addObstacles(new Obstacles(rand.nextInt(600),rand.nextInt(600)));

}}


public void paint(Graphics g){
    //paint method
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    user.draw(g2d);

    //for obstacles
    for (int i=0;i<obstacles.size();i++){
        Obstacles obst= obstacles.get(i);
        obst.draw(g2d);

       }
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // Action Listener
    user.update();

    for(int i=0; i <obstacles.size();i++){
    Obstacles obst = obstacles.get(i);  
    obst.update();
    }
    repaint();
    }


public void addObstacles(Obstacles ob){

    obstacles.add(ob);

}

 public static ArrayList<Obstacles> getObstacles(){
     return obstacles;
 }


public static void gameOver() {
    System.out.println("Game Over!");
    System.exit(0);
}


public void startgame () {
    Obstaclesnum= levelnumber *1;



    for (int i=0;i<Obstaclesnum;i++){
        addObstacles(new Obstacles(rand.nextInt(100),rand.nextInt(600)));
    }}}
```

Comment: `sleep()` not `sleeep()` :D

Comment: Oh, no sorry, typo in here, in Eclipse I used sleep() :D

Comment: Don't call `Thread.sleep`, or any other methods that cause the calling thread to block, on the EDT. Sounds as if you are. You gotta show more code. Check if you're on the EDT by calling `EventQueue.isDispatchThread()`

Comment: no problem , fixing typos is needed though :D

Comment: Going to update in a sec, showing more code.

Comment: _"he program doesnt like the "Thread Sleep" part"_ what does this mean?  :D

Comment: Come on, read to the end "all the graphics dissepear from the JFrame." :D

Comment: Updated it, if any more information is needed, please tell:)

Comment: show your code *with* the timer attempt, so we can see what you intended

Comment: One second, I'll update it again.

Comment: Your "timer" method is blocking the event dispatch thread, which is prevent it from updating the UI until the loop ends (like 10 seconds). Also, it's normally recommended that you use paintComponent

Comment: When timer are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can help you, but here you have an easy runnable timer.

```
public class Timer implements Runnable {

    private final int sec;

    public Timer(int sec) {
        this.sec = sec;
        run();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int count = sec;
        while (count > 0) {
            System.out.println(count);
            //here you can put your method to start the game.
            count--;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I have done before, the timer is going to work if I put in my program, but the game graphic dissapear for some reason.

Comment: By testing all lines of code, the Thread Sleep is what causing the graphics to dissapear.

Comment: I edit this again. I think the sleep cause your Graphics to dissapears. How I learn, you should never freeze the Mainthread

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a flag variable into your timer function.  If you are just trying to delay the action of something try something like this in your actionPerformed for the timer

```
if (counter != 0) {
    counter++;

    if (counter == 10) { // count to 10ms
        counter = 1;
        // whatever action you want done after the delay
    }
} else {
    counter = 0;
}
```